# Correct way to initialize EF Core Relationships in DotNet 8+

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

When creating an entity in EF Core with a relationship, what is the correct way to handle the initialization of said relationship property?

```cs
public class Product
{
  public Guid Id {get; set;}
  public Guid UserId {get; set;}

  public Virtual User User {get; set;}   
  public Virtual ICollection<ProductVariation> Variations {get; set;}
}
```

With the following example, Rider gives me a list of a couple problems where I need to initialize `User` and `Variations`

`Non-nullable property 'User' is uninitialized. Consider declaring the property as nullable.`

I can "fix" it by changing the relationships to

```cs
public Virtual User User {get; set;} = null!;
public Virtual ICollection<ProductVariation> Variations {get; set;} = new List<ProductVariation>();
```

The documentation examples all show it without any initialization.

What is the best way to handle these relationships?

Comment: Insead on null! use default!

Comment: You need to use nullabe properties as they can be null when you read ``Product`` without including relations! so the best way is using: ``public Virtual User? User {get; set;}``

Comment: Don't create collections in domain models like this.  it allows of wholesale replacement of the collection.  Read about [encapsulated collections](https://www.jimmybogard.com/domain-driven-refactoring-encapsulating-collections/)